# How do I get guillemets in a listing?

Tags: listings, punctuation, unicode

I'm wondering if it's possible to use guillemets («») in a `lstlisting` block?
I have seen some solutions for including it in the document, but none with the `listings` package.

Comment: @lockstep: why the tag "punctuation"?

Comment: @Herbert Guillemets are a kind of quotation mark, for which we normally use [tag:punctuation]. Perhaps [tag:characters] or [tag:symbols] would have been appropriate as alternative tags. I have no strong opinion here, so feel free to revert my tag selection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{bera,listings,babel}
\lstset{literate={«}{{\flqq}}1 {»}{{\frqq}}1}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily]
my «foo» and my «bar»
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: with `xelatex`you can do a `morecomment=[s]{«}{»}`

Comment: Which part of your answer was the crucial part? What's `bera` for? What does `\lstset` do? Why are there numbers? I could look the answers to these questions up, of course, but I think it's good style on SE sites not only to provide code, but to explain what's going on and why the answer given works. I'd love to see more explanations in your great answers!